# Qlik Sense: Change date field format from Google Analytics API

Tags: date, datetime, format, google-analytics-api, qliksense

I've pulled in data in Qlik Sense (cloud) from the Google Analytics connector. I'm trying to convert the standard date [ga_dateHourMinute] field to a more eligible date format.

The current format is YearMonthDayhHourMinute, for instance: 201810250004, I would like to convert this to the standard date format 2018-10-25 00:04:00. How do I do this? Answers concerning methods in the data load script or master formula's or variables are all welcome.

[Click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IQXR.png): left = current date format and right = desired date format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a text fields that combined the different digits from the one field into a new order, then pushed the data format into a date/time. Quite a bit of work, but fairly solid.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach:

```
DateAlter:
LOAD * INLINE [ 
Date
201810250004
];

DateAlter2:
LOAD
Date(Date#([Date], 'YYYYMMDDhhmm') ,'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm') AS [MyDateField]
Resident
DateAlter;
```

If you haven't played around with the data manager, it will allow you to edit fields and handle dates in a fairly easy manner:
[Qlik Sense Data Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVkQO.png)